# I have an string and i want to delete from a specific character to the end of the string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string

i have this string => `someRandomText&ab_channel=thisPartCanChange` and i want to delete all from `&` (inclusive) to the end [this part: `&ab_channel=thisPartCanChange`].

How can i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You van try something like:

```js
console.log("someRandomText&ab_channel=thisPartCanChange".split("&")[0])
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
const yourString = 'SomeRandomText&ab_channel=thisPartCanChange'
console.log(yourString.split('&ab_channel')[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do a regex replacement on `&.*$` and replace with empty string.

```js
var inputs = ["someRandomText&ab_channel=thisPartCanChange", "someRandomText"];
inputs.forEach(x => console.log(x.replace(/&.*$/, "")));
```

Note that the above approach is robust with regard to strings which don't even have a `&` component.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [substring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) which extract the characters between two specified index without changing the original string

```js
const yourString = 'someRandomText&ab_channel=thisPartCanChange';
const newStr = yourString.substring(0, yourString.indexOf('&'));
console.log(newStr)
```